# Sign in with LinkedIn (Web/Oauth and Mobile/SDK integrated)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, linkedin-api

I have both mobile apps (android/ios) and a website that needs to sign in using linkedin.

On the website, using OAuth is working ok, so no issues there.
The issue I'm having is related to "Sign In" using the mobile SDK, because I need to send an access token to my website server in order to identify that the user is connected and authorized via linkedin.

According to the documentation ( https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth )

> Mobile vs. server-side access tokens
>
> It is important to note that access tokens that are acquired via the Mobile SDK > are only useable with the Mobile SDK, and cannot be used to make server-side
> REST API calls.
>
> Similarly, access tokens that you already have stored from your users that
> authenticated using a server-side REST API call will not work with the Mobile
> SDK.

So I see no way of using both solutions (web and integrated) in this scenario. If I use a WebView on mobile to connect to the app and sync with my website server, the user experience is not very nice (the webview does not sync cookies, the user has to authenticate in a strange way and does not take advantage of having the LinkedIn app installed on the mobile.

Anyone knows how to solve such a scenario? Thanks!

Comment: You can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728109/linkedin-mobile-access-token-for-making-server-side-rest-api-calls

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It's ok.
[Authenticating with the Mobile SDK for iOS](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth)

> Mobile vs. server-side access tokens
>
> It is important to note that access tokens that are acquired via the
>   Mobile SDK are only usable with the Mobile SDK, and cannot be used to
>   make server-side REST API calls.  Similarly, access tokens that you
>   already have stored from your users that authenticated using a
>   server-side REST API call will not work with the Mobile SDK.
>
> **Presently, there is no mechanism available to exchange them.  If you require tokens that can be used in both the mobile and server-side
>   environment, you will need to implement a traditional OAuth 2.0
>   solution within your iOS environment to acquire tokens that can be
>   leveraged in both situations.**